# Dojo timing issue with dijit/registry and dojo/domReady

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I am working on a one-page application in Dojo which submits forms via ajax and returns parses the return value before rendering the page.  When I go about this I end up with a timing error.

When the following code is included via a script tag, it logs undefined:

```
require(["dijit/registry", 'dojo/domReady!'], function(registry){ console.log(registry.byId('my-id')) });
```

When I paste it in the console, I get the expected dijit widget.

I suspect that the problem is that this is firing before the page is rendered.  Is there an easy way to ensure that this happens after the current document has been fully parsed and included in the main window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should try, to add `Parser` and call the `Parser.parse()` before trying to access the widget.

This is from Dojo documentation

> Note that waiting for `dojo/domReady!` to fire is often not sufficient
>   when working with widgets. Many widgets shouldn’t be initialized or
>   accessed until the following modules load and execute:
>
> - dojo/uacss
> - dijit/hccss
> - dojo/parser

Comment: Hmmmm I have something else calling the parser and if I call it twice, Dojo doesn't like that.

Comment: Maybe I should use setInterval to retry until it is found?

Comment: I will be accepting this answer because it lead me on the right track, namely to recognize that there was necessarily a race condition here and just check/retry until found.

Comment: Note the actual problem however is a design one and the long-term aswer is to make the widget responsible for its own events......